# Export error: mesh has ngons

Tags: export, error

I've been trying to export a model to the game "transport fever" and I keep getting this error each time I try and export:

[image: export error]

Comment: Well... You need to get rid of ngons. If this is for a game, just make them tris.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read error messages more carefully, it says the mesh has **NGons** not "rignors"

NGons are poly**gons** whith N sides, that means your model that has more than four sides.

NGons are generally considered a bad modelling practice in general, and should be avoided for a multitude of reasons; and in many applications and file formats they are not even supported, so sounds like you have some cleanup to do.

Open all your meshes in *Edit Mode* and look for faces with more than 4 sides and remodel them so you have a proper quad dominant topology.

One quick (but unadvised) way to fix it it to blindly triangulate your mesh, by selecting all your faces in *Edit Mode* and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

Other less ill advised method is to transform all into quads with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

Lastly the recommended method is to properly retopologise your meshes using a [carefully planned topology](http://topologyguides.com/) that will ease future editing

Comment: How do you know when its more than 4?

Comment: You look at it and you count 1,2,3,4 edges, if it has more... Bam! that's an NGon